# SCCM - How do I increase/decrease the interval time when adding a computer to a device collection?

Tags: windows, sccm, sccm-2012, client-server

In SCCM - when I add a computer to the Devices and then to a custom device collection, it takes a long time for it to show up in the Custom Device Collection. Is there a way to manipulate this time? I'm assuming that SCCM is goes through a refresh period and when it notices a change, it adds the systems accordingly, or maybe I'm completely wrong on how that works and it's actually doing something else.

Simply put, I'd like for the computer to be added to the Custom Device Collection immediately, how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enable the **Use incremental updates for this collection** option, the default refresh interval time is **5** minutes.

[image]

You can modify the value between 1 and 1440 minutes.

[image]

You can manual update the membership immediately by click the **Update Membership** button in the Admin Console.
[image]

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance. Meanwhile, here is a similar post for your reference. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/690611ff-b6f7-4d52-b4cc-2022f983c02c/config-manager-2012-slow-updating-collection-membership?forum=configmanagergeneral

Comment: Dude, this is awesome! I'm supposed to avoid "+1" and "thanks" but I think it is well deserved given the time you took to provide a thorough answer. You rock! Much obliged, sir!

Comment: Microsoft wording in the collection-properties dialog is to be taken absolutely literally. Incremental update "adds resources" to a collection. The failure of the description to touch on the removal of resource is deliberate. Incremental updates do not remove members from a collection. I have recently verified this by tracking the number of collection members over a period of 30 days. The collection was configured with a full update every 7 days, and, the number  show a clear rhythm. They grow from day 1 to 7, then drop 8, then continue to grow again over the next 6 days before the drop again.